# Handbrake GUI Custom Preset Won't Save Encoding Speed Other Than "Fast"

Tags: ubuntu, video, encoding, handbrake

Handbrake 1.0.3 GUI Version
Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 LTS AMD64 Intel i7-920

When creating Presets Handbrake will not save "Preset" slider selections other than "fast". Selecting any other "Preset" slider setting and saving the preset results in only the "fast" slider preset being saved.

[handbrake screenshot with "Preset" Slider circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dISnz.png)

I have had success exporting the custom preset that I can make, changing .json file parameter:

"VideoPreset": "ultrafast",

Saving the .json file and importing back into Handbrake.  This is a very convoluted way of saving a very simple change made in the GUI.  How can a preset be saved with a "Preset" slider setting other than "fast" within the GUI?

Are the  .json preset files being saved somewhere in the file system in separate .json files for each preset, or is each preset merged into a large master  preset file?

Comment: This sounds eerily like a bug and should be filed with Handbrake's upstream developers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this Handbrake Software Bug in v1.0.3 of the software.

by JohnAStebbins » Wed Mar 22, 2017 3:58 pm
It's a known issue that has been fixed in the nightly builds and will be fixed in the next release.